# Left and Right multiplications

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be any group. For $x \in G$, let $r_x$ and $l_x$ be the mappings $G \to G$ defined by $$r_x(g) = gx \hspace{2mm} \text{and} \hspace{2mm} l_x(g) = xg,$$ or in other words, by right and left multiplication by $x$ on $G$. Let $R = \{r_x \mid x \in G\}$ and $L = \{l_x \mid x \in G\}$. Show that $$L = \{f \in \text{Sym}(G) \mid fr = rf \hspace{2mm} \text{for all} \hspace{2mm} r \in R\} = A,$$ where $fr(g) = r(f(g))$.

Guys, i've been stuck in this exercise for 4 days in a row now and would really appreciate help. I already proved that $L \subset A$ but the $A \subset L$ part is driving me really crazy.

Comment: $f\in A$ means that $fr_x(g)=r_xf(g)$ for all $x,g$. How does it simplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those cases where the most likely candidate works. If $f$ is going to be a left multiplication, then the thing it'd multiply by would be the same as whatever it sends the identity element to. With that mind, the solution writes itself:

Let $e$ be the identity element and suppose $f(e)=x$.

Then $f(g)=f(r_g(e))=r_g(f(e))=r_g(x)=xg=l_x(g)$.

Comment: Man, i hate how i get stuck in such simple exercises, thanks a lot.